# Group a field based on its datetime_initial and datetime_final?

Tags: mysql, sql, group

I have data like this:

```
category      datetime_initial       datetime_final

party         2022-12-26 11:17:47    2022-12-26 12:20:49
party         2022-12-26 12:20:49    2022-12-26 12:32:24
party         2022-12-26 12:32:24    2022-12-26 12:41:37
party         2022-12-26 12:41:37    2022-12-26 15:04:21
home          2022-12-26 15:04:21    2022-12-26 16:17:39   
home          2022-12-26 16:17:39    2022-12-16 18:45:13
party         2022-12-16 18:45:13    2022-12-16 18:46:08
```

I want a output like this:

```
category      datetime_initial       datetime_final

party         2022-12-26 11:17:47    2022-12-26 15:04:21
home          2022-12-26 15:04:21    2022-12-16 18:45:13
party         2022-12-16 18:45:13    2022-12-16 18:46:08
```

But I'm stuck on some solution, I've tried with procedures, however, without success...

Comment: Could you be more specific about how to filter?

Comment: @Natrium The filter would basically get the datetime_initial and datetime_final of a category until it changes. As shown, it groups the results of the 'party' category from '2022-12-26 11:17:47' to '2022-12-26 15:04:21' which is when it gets another value for the category, which is the 'home'.

Comment: Is the grouping performed on daily basis, i.e. is it possible to have a change sequence 'party - home - party' within the same day?

Comment: In your data all ranges are adjacent. But what if there is a gap or, backward, an overlapping? PS. This is common ranges concatenation task.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

We can select the earliest and the latest date using `MIN` and `MAX`.

Using `GROUP BY` category allows to fetch the two dates for every category instead of producing one single row only.

In order to get the two dates also grouped by day as shown in your question, we can also put this in the `GROUP BY` clause:

```
SELECT 
category,
MIN(datetime_initial) AS datetime_initial,
MAX(datetime_final) AS datetime_final
FROM yourtable
GROUP BY category, DATE(datetime_initial);
```

This will produce the correct three rows.

If we want to make sure these rows will exactly be ordered as in your question, we can run a row number without sorting and then order by this row number in the main query.

Thus we will apply the same "order" it has in your DB, pointing out that this is no real "order" because you don't have an id or any other column which indicates the order. We should prefer to create another table and directly save only those dates you want to get in your query here or at least we should add a column which holds the order information. This avoids such unhandy queries.

```
WITH ordered AS
(SELECT category, datetime_initial, datetime_final,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
        ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)
    ) row_num
FROM 
    yourtable)
SELECT 
category,
MIN(datetime_initial) AS datetime_initial,
MAX(datetime_final) AS datetime_final
FROM ordered
GROUP BY category, DATE(datetime_initial)
ORDER BY row_num;
```

This solution will only work correctly if we don't switch from "party" to "home" and back multiple times within the same day. If this is possible in your DB, as said, get rid of this poor structure and save the data in a better way.

See [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/fdl30vmn)